# Map changing the order of key value pairs in apex

Tags: apex, list, map, order

I am creating a map from a string stored in a specific format. But Adding the key-value pairs and later displaying it, I notice the order is not maintained on the map. Is it possible to maintain the order in which key-value pairs are added.

```
Map<String, String> FieldLabelMap = new Map<String, String>();
    String fields = 'status,Status;Reason,Type;CaseNumber,Case Number;SecondaryReason,Case Reason';
    List<String> fieldAPIList = fields.split(';');
    system.debug('list#'+fieldAPIList[0]);
    for(String fieldvar : fieldAPIList){
        List<String> Stringvar = fieldvar.split(',');
        system.debug(Stringvar[0]+'#'+Stringvar[1]);
        FieldLabelMap.put(Stringvar[0],Stringvar[1]);  
    }
    system.debug('##FieldLabelMap'+FieldLabelMap);

    output : ##FieldLabelMap{CaseNumber=Case Number, Reason=Type, Secondary_Case_Layout__c=Case Reason, status=Status}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maps are *unordered* collections, and may be organized in any order. Note that [Iteration Order for Maps and Sets Is Now Predictable](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_apex_maps_and_sets_iteration_order.htm) causes the values to be displayed in a consistent order, which is why they appear to be ordered alphabetically. If you want the order to *definitely* be preserved, return the keys in the order you would like.

```
public class ReturnValue {
  @AuraEnabled String[] keys;
  @AuraEnabled Map<String, String> values;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static ReturnValue fetchLabelsMap() {
    ReturnValue fieldValues = new ReturnValue();
    fieldValues.keys = new String[0];
    fieldValues.values = new Map<String, String>();
    String fields = 'status,Status;Reason,Type;CaseNumber,Case Number;SecondaryReason,Case Reason';
    List<String> fieldAPIList = fields.split(';');
    for(String fieldvar : fieldAPIList){
        List<String> Stringvar = fieldvar.split(',');
        fieldValues.keys.add(Stringvar[0]);
        fieldValues.values.put(Stringvar[0],Stringvar[1]);  
    }
    return fieldValues;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will check and update.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are great !!